# Back and forth emails and letters

Tags: text, email

For a research project, I am currently looking for datasets that consists of large amounts of e-mails, text messages, or OCR-processed letters that were written as part of a conversational exchange between two people.

There are quite a few open datasets that include a (significant amount) of emails. For instance, one has the [Enron dataset](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~enron/), the [Jeb Bush dataset](https://github.com/hical/sample-dataset), and the [Hillary Clinton dataset](https://wikileaks.org/clinton-emails/). However, these datasets are not exactly what I'm looking for.

I'd like to have a dataset that consists of a large amount of (written) conversations between exactly two people. The emails should alternate between these two people, with one email (or letter or text message) for each person, each time.

**Question**: do such open datasets exist? If so, where can I find them?